# Проблема при создании json объекта

Tags: ios, json, ios7

Доброго времени суток!

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так: когда я создаю JSON-объект

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

у меня возникают проблемы с кириллицей: `\U0418\U043d\U0444\U043e\U0440\U043c\U0430\`.

Я не знаю, что с этим делать. Подскажите пожалуйста, буду признателен! Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся!

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"login=%@&pass=%@",[txtUserName text],[txtPassword text]];

```
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://chgu.org/?mobile=1"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: Покажите больше кода. Как вы получаете response?

Comment: Кроме того, просто для проверки сделайте:

    NSString *justToCheckString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Видим ли мы нормальные строки или нет: @ ?", justToCheckString);

Получаются ли у вас нормальные строки?

Comment: я делал!!! когда я проверяю все отлично !!! но стоит мне сделать NSJSONSerialization все меняется вся кириллица превращается в \U0418\U043d и так далее

Comment: Теперь покажите код response - как он у вас получается? Добавьте его в ответ.

Comment: я подредактировал вопрос и туда добавил по больше кода!!!
Буду признателен если вы мне подскажите как правильно писать!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых это "\U0418\U043d\U0444\U043e\U0440\U043c\U0430." не проблеммы с кирилицей, а обычное escape шифрование, для того чтоб можно было передавать UTF8 по сети без всяких проблем. Во-вторых, NSJSONSerialization хоть и выводит вам в NSLog в escape, ни чего страшного, при чтении текста любыми вьюхами типа UILabel будет успешно и по русски и по китайски для этого и стоит значек \U говорящий, что это кодировка UTF8.
В-третьих, раз уж Вам так хочется читать в NSLog русские буковки, то можете попробывать следующий код конвертирующий escape:

```
NSString *name2escaped = @"Nu\\u0161a Florjan\\u010di\\u010d---- \\U0418\\U043d";
NSString *name2 = [NSString stringWithCString:[name2escaped     cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"name2 = %@", name2);
```

Ну, а если особо пофиг я просто копирую текст в терминал и прогоняю через echo "\U0418\U043d\U0444\U043e\U0440\U043c\U0430."

**UPD**
 Как вариант можете заюзать сторонню либу для парсинга JSON такие как: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!